# What's wrong to my solution of this probabilistic proof of existence problem?

Tags: probability, self-study

**Question** A hundred students have taken an exam consisting of 8 problems, and for each
problem at least 65 of the students got the right answer. Show that there exist
two students who collectively got everything right, in the sense that for each
problem, at least one of the two got it right.

**Correct solution** Say that the “score” of a pair of students is how many problems at least one of
them got right. The expected score of a random pair of students (with all pairs
equally likely) is at least $8(1-0.35^2)=7.02$, as seen by creating an indicator r.v. for each problem for the event that at least one student in the pair got it right. (We can also improve the $0.35^2$ to $\frac{35}{100}\times \frac{34}{99}$ since the students are sampled
without replacement.) So some pair of students must have gotten a score of at
least $7.02$, which means that they got a score of 8! (not a factorial.)

**My solution** I took the expected number of pairs of students that get all 8 questions correct instead. So since there are $100 \choose 2$ pairs of students, each of them being an indicator r.v. with probability of success $(1-0.35^2)^8$, then we get an expected number of pair of students that collectively got all questions right ${100 \choose 2} \times (1-0.35^2)^8 \approx 1740$. I'm not sure what we can conclude from this, but it seems incredibly unlikely that $0$ pairs succeeded if the expected number is $1740$. Is this probability still non null though...?

Comment: What rule of probability, and what assumptions, justify taking the eighth power in your solution?  I believe that the assumptions needed are not present in the question but have been implicitly adduced in your answer.

Comment: Ah...! So I was assuming the students' answers to different problems are independent, which I can't do, right?